# Where is the order of a menu saved in the database

Tags: menus, database, order

I want to use a custom menu from the wordpress database but I get the elements disordered and I want them to have the same order how can i do that? There is a place in the database where the order is stored?

Comment: I haven't confirmed this, but I would assume that since nav menus use the `{prefix}_posts` table, they would also use the `menu_order` column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is custom menu hierarchy output handled?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70872/how-is-custom-menu-hierarchy-output-handled)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get the nav_menu_items from `wp_term_relationship` in correct order. if you want to confirm there order by knowing there order number... u will get the object id of each item from the previous table and search for that id in `wp_posts`. then there will be column for that particular row named `menu_order`. so that u can get the actual order number.

Answer (score 0):

old post but a weird answer, maybe this is more current:  fields for a post are either in the wp_posts table or the wp_postmeta, the one for menu_order is in wp_posts.

You can use the menu_order sorting for products in a shortcode like this:

```
[products order_by="menu_order" order="DESC" limit="-1" per_page="24" paginate="true"]
```

In my case, I imported products and their import order wasn't the same as the original date created.  So by populating menu_order and using that shortcode I'm able to show a list new product releases in the correct order.